# Python Regex only matches part of the password of a set of characters

Tags: python

Im trying to validate Email:pass info from a file.

Heres my Python code:

```py
with open(filename, "r+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        match = re.search(
            '^[a-z0-9_.+-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-.]+:[a-z0-9-.!-?@]+', line)
        if match:
            a = match.group()
            print(a)
            f.write(a+"\n")

f.close()
EndTime()
```

Heres my Text:

```
bigsuffolk@hotmail.com:Allthetime1! | Expire Date = 4/1/2022 | Remaining Days = 701
kendrixquincy@gmail.com:Monster3! | Expire Date = 11/2/2020 | Remaining Days = 186
mcfatigue@gmail.com:!Lucario1 | Expire Date = 2/6/2021 | Remaining Days = 282
```

My Output:

```
comnavguy@gmail.com:1qaz@
dfriddell@sbcglobal.net:85
jon.d.rowland@gmail.com:12qw!@
adam.dubree@gmail.com:1022
```

My Regex:

```py
'^[a-z0-9_.+-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-.]+:[a-z0-9-.!-?@]+'
```

The passwords always have all kinds of special characters.

Why my regular expression doesn't match the whole passwords?

Comment: Your example doesn't show any input lines that actually matched, and it doesn't show any input lines that should have matched but didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression seems to lack **capitals letters** to match your passwords.

```py
regstr = r'^[a-z0-9_.+-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-.]+:[a-zA-Z0-9-.!-?@]+'
```

(the regular expression could be written in a more concise way)